# How to make multiple request and responses from all the requests in Retrofit, RxJava, Android

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java, rx-android

I have a scenario where I want to call same API for multiple devices and display result after completing all requests.
I am using retrofit 2.
I know little bit about RxJava. I thought zip operator will be suitable for this. So implemented as below.

API in `ApiInterface` :

```
@PUT(AppConstants.BASE_URL + AppConstants.PATH_SEPARATOR + "/user/endpoint")
Observable<ResponseBody> updateInfo(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Query("device_id") String deviceId, @Body JsonObject body);
```

Here is a method which calls API. It gets device id and its body in Map. This method calls API for every device id available in Map.

```
public void updateAllInfo(final HashMap<String, String> deviceIdMap, final ApiResponseListener listener) {

    List<Observable<ResponseBody>> requests = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> reqIdList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        String deviceId = entry.getKey();
        String jsonBodyStr = entry.getValue();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject jsonBody = gson.fromJson(jsonBodyStr, JsonObject.class);

        reqIdList.add(deviceId);
        requests.add(apiInterface.updateSchedules("accessToken", deviceId, jsonBody));
    }

    Observable.zip(requests, new Function<Object[], List<ResponseBody>>() {

        @Override
        public List<ResponseBody> apply(Object[] objects) throws Exception {

            Log.e("onSubscribe", "apply : " + objects.length);
            List<ResponseBody> dataResponses = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Object o : objects) {
                dataResponses.add((ResponseBody) o);
            }
            return dataResponses;
        }
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<List<ResponseBody>>() {

                @Override
                public void accept(List<ResponseBody> responseBodies) throws Exception {
                    Log.e("onSubscribe", "YOUR DATA IS HERE: " + responseBodies.size());
                    for (int i = 0; i < responseBodies.size(); i++) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Response received for " + i + " is : " + responseBodies.get(i).string());
                    }
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    Log.e("onSubscribe", "Throwable: " + throwable);
                }
            });
}
```

I want to get the response (success / failure) for every device id. Means I need response and also id for which API is called.
Using zip operator, if any API is failed, failure is received in `accept(Throwable throwable)` method. If any API is failed, I think zip operator is not calling next API.

How can I get response (success or failure) for all request ?

Also need something to indicate the response is for which req / device id (Some mapping) to display result.

Is there any other operator I can use instead of zip ?

Any suggestion / help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a bit rusty in java, so I will write my answer in Kotlin, it should not be a problem for you to convert it yourself.

Create a helper class that will include the `ResponseBody` alongside with the `deviceId`:

```
data class IdentifiedResponseBody(
    val deviceId: String, 
    val responseBody: ResponseBody?
)
```

Then:

```
// change the signature of your requests list to return IdentifiedResponseBody observables
val requests = mutableListOf<Observable<IdentifiedResponseBody>>()
...
// your stated API have updateInfo instead of updateSchedules, but I will assume they have the same signature
requests.add(
    apiInterface.updateSchedules("accessToken", deviceId, jsonBody)
        .map { responseBody ->
            // map the added observable to return IdentifiedResponseBody
            IdentifiedResponseBody(deviceId, responseBody)
        }
        .onErrorReturn { error -> 
            // return an item here instead of throwing error, so that the other observables will still execute
            IdentifiedResponseBody(deviceId, null)
        }
)
```

Finally, use `merge` instead of `zip`:

```
Observable.merge(requests)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        // it's a question if you want to observe these on main thread, depends on context of your application
        .subscribe(
            { identifiedResponse ->
                // here you get both the deviceId and the responseBody
                Log.d("RESPNOSE", "deviceId=${identifiedResponse.deviceId}, body=${identifiedResponse.responseBody}")
                if (responseBody == null || responseBody.hasError()) {
                    // request for this deviceId failed, handle it
                }
            },
            { error ->
                Log.e("onSubscribe", "Throwable: " + error)
            }
        )
```

See `merge`: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html

See `zip`: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

You should see the profound difference: `zip` combines your responses to one single item defined by your mapping function (i.e.  list of responses in your case), while `merge` emits all responses individually, at the time they are returned. In case of `zip` here, the combined result is returned at the moment (and only) when all the requests have finished; you may not want this behavior, as if a single request would not return a response, you would not get any response at all.

**UPDATE**

The java equivalent should be as follow, but revise before trying out, as I am not sure if I converted everything correctly:

```
requests.add(
    apiInterface.updateSchedules("accessToken", deviceId, jsonBody)
                .map(new Function<ResponseBody, IdentifiedResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public IdentifiedResponseBody apply(ResponseBody responseBody) throws Exception {
                        return new IdentifiedResponseBody(deviceId, responseBody);
                    }
                })
                .onErrorReturn(new Function<Throwable, IdentifiedResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public IdentifiedResponseBody apply(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        return new IdentifiedResponseBody(deviceId, null);
                    }
                })
        );

Observable.merge(requests)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<IdentifiedResponseBody>() {
                           @Override
                           public void accept(IdentifiedResponseBody identifiedResponseBody) throws Exception {
                               // same logic as from kotlin part
                           }
                       },
                    new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                            Log.e("onSubscribe", "Throwable: " + throwable);
                        }
                    });
```

**UPDATE 2**

In the comment you asked:

> Is there any way from which I can get final callback for all requests
> completed

That's the problem with using `Observable` instead of `Single`/`Completable`, it just does not finish unless you explicitly close the channel or an error is thrown. In ideal context, `Observable` should be used for streams that continuously emits some data, for example an open channel to Room DB, as there are no telling how many time the DB will change. I admit that in your case it seems to be difficult to apply something else than `Observable`. There is however a workaround:

```
Observable.merge(requests)
    // emits only this much items, then close this channel
    .take(requests.size.toLong())
    // executed when the channel is closed or disposed
    .doFinally {
         // todo: finalCallback
     }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(...)
```

The code is again in Kotlin, should not be hard to transform to java. Please check what `Observable.take()` does: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html

Comment: Thank you so much for help. Much appreciated.

Comment: One more query for this answer. Is there any way from which I can get final callback for all requests completed ?

Comment: Great answer. I thought I need a manual count variable for this. Thank you so much.